# Close file after reading in powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there anyway to close the file after reading it in powereshell?

Current Code : `Get-Content sample.txt`

With some googling I found 2 commands Get-SmbOpenFile and Close-SmbOpenFile. However both are not returning any response.

Comment: `Get-Content` automatically closes the underlying file handle when it's done. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Its actually a shared file, at times I'm noticing the file locked error. Completely unaware of the command in other script which reads the file.

Comment: if you know the script that is also accessing the file, then you can add a `mutex` to allow shared file access. however, a FAR easier solution is to always use unique names for your various files. if needed, copy the file to a new name and then work with the copy.

Comment: ^ Above.
Hard drive space is cheap, RAM is expensive.

Comment: One additional note: Third-party anti-virus or security software could also be involved, especially if the file type is scanned during on-access read operations.  Thus, if this is a large file (or a compressed file) located on a network share, then I might advise to add an on-access scan exclusion for it.  Worth a mention.

Comment: Please go back to step 1 (@MathiasR.Jessen suggestion) how do you know the file is left open by `Get-Content` ("*after reading in powershell*") ??? which is highly unlikely as you also only reading the file. More likely is that you locking the file from somewhere else...

Comment: Do you pipe the results into a (slow) pipeline, like: `Get-Content sample.txt | Slow-Command ...`? If yes, you might try: `(Get-Content sample.txt) | Slow-Command ...` which reads the contents in once and than passes it into the pipeline.